# Filtering and grouping in Python Model Objects after querying the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='item',on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    email = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    .....
```

I need to send an email to `user`, where `Item` `email` attribute is `False`.

I have the following query:

```
 items = Item.objects.filter(email=False)
```

I want to filter/group item by User. I want to do it python because I want to send emails with delay and not to overwhelm the database at once with many queries.

For each use I want to create a `context` dictionary that I can sent to the Django Email.

A pseudo code/logic:

```
  user_context { 
      'subject' : 'some subject'}

 for item in items:
   if user is the same:
    user_context['content] = append item

    if finished same_user items:
      send_email(user_context)
      context = {} # reset context
```

Comment: But here a `User` can have *zero*, *one* or *multiple* `Item`s. What should happen in case *no* or *multiple* `Item`s exist for a `User`?

Comment: if multiple group items and send them all at the same time(this is what I'm trying to do). The item cannot be created without an User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group an iterable into an iterable of 2-tuples. In order to process this effectively, it is however important to do some prefetching of (related) `User` objects, like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

qs = Item.objects.filter(email=False).order_by('user_id').prefetch_related('user')

result = [
    (k, list(vs))
    for k, v in groupby(qs, key=attrgetter('user'))
]
```

Now `result` is a list of 2-tuples: the first element of every tuple contains the related `User` object, the second item of a tuple the list of relevant `Item` objects (with `email=False`). `User`s with no such `Item`s will *not* be in the list.

So in case you want to send an email, you can loop over the list of 2-tuples like:

```
for user, items in result:
    user_context { 
        'subject' : 'some subject'
    }
    user_context['content] = items
    send_email(user_context)
```

If you are however *only* intersted in the `User`s where there exist an `Item` with `email=False`, then you only need to query:

```
User.objects.filter(item__email=False)
```

Comment: I update my question with a pseudo code/logic to be more clear what I'm trying to do